# CMS with real-time collaboration/co-authoring (like Google Docs)?

Tags: cms, collaboration

Is there any CMS with real-time collaboration tools like Google Docs?

I mean it's very convenient when authors can simultaneously open the same article (text, maybe HTML) and edit it, then publish it on the web. We currently use Google Docs for it, but want to integrate that to publishing process.

Something like [Real-time co-authoring in Office Web Apps](http://blogs.office.com/2013/11/06/collaboration-just-got-easier-real-time-co-authoring-now-available-in-office-web-apps/) (as shown for Word App), but inside a CMS like WordPress.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/) to generate the text collaboratively. Typo3 has an [Etherpad integration](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/bb_etherpad), but I haven't used it.

Etherpad is a collaborative real-time text editor that lets you export your result as HTML, Text etc. The empathizes of etherpad is the real-time. You type stuff and the other users sees it instantly.

It's very narrow in its features (no images IIRC) but should be sufficient if all you need is text.

As Etherpad has an export button already build it you could use this to add your own export button and send the generated HTML to wherever you want.

You might want to read this SO post: [Etherpad and Wordpress, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3559922)

I used Etherpad with other people together in a political party. But we didn't include it in our CMS directly (never had the need).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with real-time collaboration and CMSs is that most of these are built in PHP which doesn't support concurrent editing.

However, apart from EtherPad, there's also [Share.js](https://github.com/share/ShareJS), a node.js application which enables real-time collaboration, as well as [together.js](https://togetherjs.com/) which is mostly client side solution which enables real-time collaboration over built in editors. It can be integrated to most of the popular HTML editors for the web.

Another possible solution (actually a workaround...) is the [Google Docs to WordPress](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-to-wordpress/nbljnjmeckdecofjohdobgmleppiikll?hl=en) integration add-on which allows you to edit together on Google and later publish in WP.

Answer (score 1):

[Hackpad](https://hackpad.com/) is the software you are looking for. My team at my company uses it and it's really good, and it also integrates(or can be embedded) in Wordpress.

And I would also recommend [Workflowy](https://workflowy.com/) which can be used as a collaborative editor and also for designing workflow for meeting and presentations, and it is also embeddable in Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use hackpad, but didn't know that it can be integrated - that's interesting, I'll try. And workflowy is totally great, I always structure my subtasks in any tasks managers/issue trackers as lists, exactly how workflow do it but with simple text/markup - seems like the tool I always wanted but never know.

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you.  I use them on a daily basis. So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

[Bluo cms](https://bluocms.com/) has built in real time collaboration just like in Google docs.

**Update**

> Could you please give a bit more information as to why this is a good fit.

- Real time collaboration like google docs.
- You can edit and then press publish and you can see it live on your website.
- You can see history of changes, how long it took to write each line of text and by whom. (Managers can see the cost of the article as well)
- Has a publishing workflow, for example writers can't publish themselves. After written is reviewed and then published.
- Very reliable as the website can't crash like Wordpress. I don't need to worry about viruses and db migrations etc..

@Chenmunka

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

I updated the answer here.

> Could you please add a screenshot showing realtime collaboration? Also, where can it be downloaded? If it is SaaS, where is the signup page? Thanks! –

I could make a video when I'm free, but basically is the same as google docs. Different toolbar design, but intuitive.

It's a SaaS system. I signed up through a friend. Sign up on the waiting list to try it out faster.

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information as to why this is a good fit.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/62418)

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot showing realtime collaboration? Also, where can it be downloaded? If it is SaaS, where is the signup page? Thanks!